# Getting error in generated iPhone simulator build .zip file for submit in Facebook for review in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, zip, ios-simulator, review

I am created a .zip for facebook app review by following command.

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` ./Desktop/appName.zip
```

After successfully created In terminal launch .zip file using following command

```
ios-sim launch /path/to/appName.zip
```

that time getting error

> /path/to/appName.zip/Info.plist file not found.

but when I open .zip file in it Info.plist is present

how to solve this problem.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to extract the zip file first.

`appName.zip` will become `appName.app`. And then you provide that new file's path.

So it's:

ios-sim launch /path/to/appName.**app**

And not

ios-sim launch /path/to/appName.**zip**